# Do defined (#define) constants in C represent values without a data type?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define LOWERLIMIT 5
#define UPPERLIMIT 30
```

Do defined (#define) constants in C represent values without a data type?

Comment: They're preprocessor directives which just replace the text e.g. LOWERLIMIT with something else e.g. 5. They don't have 'types' as such.

Comment: Previously the preprocessor was a separate program that ran before the compiler, and what it does with macros such as your is a simple search-replace. Each time it sees e.g. `LOWERLIMIT` in the input it outputs `5`. The compiler never sees `LOWERLIMIT` only the integer literal `5`.

Comment: `LOWERLIMIT` etc. are no constants. They are macros inserting constants. `5` etc. are constants in C. There are no symbolic constants in C other than _enum-constants_ (which are always `int`, btw)

Answer (score 0):

`#define` is just a directive that preprocessor uses to perform simple text replacements. And about your case:

```
#define LOWERLIMIT 5
#define UPPERLIMIT 30
```

both macro definitions are expanded to integer literals without any suffixes, so effectively your macro represent constants with type `int`.

Comment: "your macro represent constants with type int" Unless they're assigned to another variable type, like a character?

Comment: @iwin Question is about type of expression that we've got after macro expansion, not about result of any extra operations.

Comment: `5` etc. are _integer **constants**_ according to the standard. There are only _string **literals**_. And the type is not only determined by the suffix, but also by the value. (agreed about the values shown are indeed `int`)

Comment: That is not exact, since you can use a macro inside of another macro and, say, concatenate it with a suffix. Or with a decimal point with fractional part. Or even append it to some letters and get a variable or function name. So... it's just a code text, no types numbers or whatever.